# Error: PYTHON DJANGO PRAW REDDIT-API

Tags: python, django, reddit, praw

building locally a Django 1.8 web app in a Python 2.7 virtual env using Praw 4.4.0.

The project is called `demonstration` and has an app called `app`

[image]

Atm,

[image]

This is part of the result when going to: http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/profile/

app/views.py has the following code for profile:

```
# views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
import requests
import praw


# Create your views here.
    def profile(request):
        reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='client_id',
                      client_secret='client_secret',
                      username='username',
                      password='password',
                      user_agent='user_agent')
        # assume you have a Reddit instance bound to variable `reddit`
        subreddit = reddit.subreddit('redditdev')

        print(subreddit.display_name)  # Output: redditdev
        print(subreddit.title)  # Output: reddit Development
        print(subreddit.description)  # Output: A subreddit for discussion of ...
```

As you can see in the second image, the name of the subreddit gets printed. **Great**.

*Well, not so great.* That was written in the code, so it's not picking up from Reddit, see:

```
subreddit = reddit.subreddit('redditdev')

print(subreddit.display_name)  # Output: redditdev
```

Once it actually tries to go to Reddit and suck up the data, this is the result:

```
print(subreddit.title)  # Output: reddit Development
print(subreddit.description)  # Output: A subreddit for discussion of ...
```

> [01/Mar/2017 14:50:02]"GET /app/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 500 93288

Using `Debug mode = True`, one can see the following in the page:

[image]

**Problem:** somehow, Reddit is not liking my login.

**How can they start to like me and allow me to print the data?**

**What can I do better?**

*Thank you for your support*

\\\\\Some helpful links////////

http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/quick_start.html

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/praw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed.
The problem was:

```
username='username',
password='password',
```

Removed it and then started to work.

[image]